# String to string less than comparison

Tags: ruby

If I do `'5' <= '12'`, I get `false` as a result. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String#<=>` compares the first characters of the strings, then the next characters of the strings, and so on, similar to how you'd compare strings if you were alphabetizing them. `'5' <= '12'` is false because `'5' <= '1'` is false.

Comment: @BenNelson if you want to compare them as integers, use `to_i` like so: `'5'.to_i <= '12'.to_i`

Comment: @MikeSlutsky whoops, fixed it

Comment: It would be more frustrating if the result were `true`.

Answer (score 3):

> If I do '5' <= '12' I get false as a result. Why?

Because the string `'5'` *is* less than the string `'12'`. Everything else wouldn't make sense. It's exactly the same as `'e' <= 'ab' # => false` (Note that I deliberately picked the fifth, first, and second letters of the alphabet to show how the two examples match exactly.)

```
'5' <= '12' # => false
'e' <= 'ab' # => false
#5      12
 5  <=  12  # => true
#of course, the *number* 5 is less than the number 12
```